# Why do I need more than one node in order to simple index document?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to study `elasticsearch` and test it with python.

I'm running with the following versions:

- windows 10
- elasticserach 7.5.1
- python 3.7.3

I run elastic search (double click on bin/elasticsearch.bat) and run the following python script:

(which I tooked from https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/0

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

doc = {
    'author': 'kimchy',
    'text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.',
    'timestamp': datetime.now(),
}
res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc)
```

But I'm getting exceptions:

```
Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
....
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
... Python37\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 238, in perform_request
    method, url, body, retries=Retry(False), headers=request_headers, **kw
...exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)...
```

when I check `localhst:9200` is seems that elasticsearch is not running

If I'm running another node:

```
elasticsearch.bat-Epath.data=data2 -Epath.logs=log2
```

I can see it run (`localhst:9200`) and getting no exceptions.

It seems so simple, but what am I doing wrong ? Why do I need to run more than one node ?

Comment: what is the result `netstat /noa | find "9200"` on cmd

Comment: Are you open `http://localhost: 9200/` in a browser?

Comment: Just after running another node (elasticsearch.bat-Epath.data=data2 -Epath.logs=log2) everything works and I can see it on broswer. why is this ?

Comment: I tried to check if the service is running normally. anyway.